# Executing CMD commands in Powershell IDE lets shell idle

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, 7zip

Im making a powershell script that lets me install a certain software and i cant use certain powershell commands because i have to execute the script on multiple environments (PS 2-5.1)

So i try to unzip files with this command because all the clients have 7zip and Windows installed.

`cmd.exe --% 7z x C:\ProgramFiles\OpenSSH-Win64.zip'`

But the ouput is simply: (sorry for the german)

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.356]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.
```

And the rest of the scripts is not being executed... its in some idle state which I can interrupt with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Am i missing something? Why is the command not being executed and the script continued?

Thanks for the help :)

---

Further Information:

[CMD Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTEss.png)

[Powershell Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ7aD.png)

Comment: Whats with the ' that terminates the command, that looks wrong, and maybe you want to use cmd.exe /c

Comment: Did you know that Powershell is - just like cmd - a command line interface. You can run `7z.exe` directly. You don't need to call another command line interpreter (cmd) from your current command line interpreter (Powershell). ;-)

Comment: I removed the ' and replaced --% with /c but no improvement, using the 7z or 7z.exe command directly in powershell tells me "No such cmdlet, script.... found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Invoke-Command [path to 7z.exe] x 'C:\ProgramFiles\OpenSSH-Win64.zip'
```

If that doesn't work, try

```
Invoke-Command [path to 7z.exe] --% x C:\ProgramFiles\OpenSSH-Win64.zip'
```

You can use `&` instead of `Invoke-Command`

Comment: So the command that worked for me was: 


`& 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' e C:\ProgramFiles\OpenSSH-Win64.zip -oc:\ProgramFiles\OpenSSH-Win64 * -r`


Thank you very much :))